# Show a popup on redirect from old to new domain

Tags: redirect, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I need to show a popup when the old domain is redirected to new domain in the nuxt js.

I have modified the . htaccess file and have a modal in the index.vue.

```
mounted() {
 const modal = document.getElementById('modal')
  if (document.referrer.indexOf('https://olddomain.com') > -1) {
   alert('Previous domain redirected')
   modal.style.display = 'block'
  }
}
```

But there is no popup displayed. Is there a better way to do this using nuxt.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

Create a middleware in `middleware/popupCheck.js` name is up to you..

when you are creating middleware in Nuxt you should export default function, like this:

```
export default function(context) {
  if (context.req.headers['your-custom-header']) {
    // Use vuex store to dispatch an action to show a popup or set a cookie
    // to listen to. Here the logic should be defined by the implementation.
  }
}
```

The point here is to listen for a header in the request, could be a cookie also, that you have to send from your old site for every request, so make sure it's not something generic, but instead something that you cannot hit easily by mistake..

After you create your middleware you can use it on `pages` or `layouts` views, and you should add it in the default object you export:

```
export default {
  middleware: 'popupCheck',
}
```

Without importing the middleware you just call it by name, this could also be an array if you wish to add multiple middlewares, and the order in that array is important.

There might be a better way to solve this, but this is the first one that came to my mind..